# Security redirection

Tags: php, codeigniter, security

My question is about CodeIgniter secure redirection.
Let's say we have an user and this user has multiple recipients. And also a table with them (CodeIgnitier framework). If I want to edit some of the user's recipients I just click the edit button. Then this action will redirect the user to edit recipient page.

In my codeigniter I'm using:

```
public fuction editRecipient($recipien_id)
{
...
}
```

If I organize my function in this way, users can access the edit page of another recipient (by Url: htttp://example.com/editRecipient/123/)

So, what would be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should be an [Access Control List](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_Control_List).

Comment: afaik there is no ACL included in codeigniter, although I am not a pro here. A quick google search fore codeigniter and ACL does however bring up several possible solutions. I am sure you can find one that is suitable for you too.